# Breakpoints not working debugging React app in Chrome through Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 and WSL2

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

After this year's MSBuild conference and the announcement of Terminal 1.x, winget and other extras, I wanted to give Windows 10 another test run ahead of needing to purchase a new laptop (Surface Book 3 or MacBook Pro...that is the question).

**The Issue**

Breakpoints aren't working when debugging web apps in Chrome on Windows 10 using WSL2 and Visual Studio Code.  When running a debug session the message **Breakpoint set but not yet bound** is shown.

The exact same app works flawlessly when debugging on MacOS.

**My Setup**

MacBook Pro running the latest version of MacOS with Windows 10 Pro installed under BootCamp.

Windows 10 has WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04.  Terminal 1.x is installed and used to access the Linux commandline.

Visual Studio Code is the latest 1.45.1 stable release and includes the WSL remote development extension (0.44.2) on Windows 10.  VSCode is launched from within WSL2 by running `code .` within the project directory.

Debugger for Chrome extension is 4.12.8

**The Application**

The application is a default Create React App with only a small change to assign breakpoints.

I start by running:

```
npx create-react-app sandbox
```

I then simplified `src/App.js` and added a few arbitrary variables and assignments to use as breakpoint tests.

The `App.js` file contents.

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/main.css';

function App() {
  const test = true;
  let temp = 9;
  temp = 10;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Breakpoint test</h1>
      <p>Did it work?</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I place a breakpoint on the `const` and `let` creation lines as well as the reassignment of `temp`.

My `launch.json` contents as recommended by the [Create React App editor setup documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#visual-studio-code).

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Win10 - What happens when running a Debug session?**

I run the Create React App using `npm run start` and when I run the Launch Chrome debug config it automatically opens Chrome as expected.

Unfortunately, the breakpoints are ignored and inside Visual Studio Code the breakpoints are shown as unfilled circles. The message given is **Breakpoint set but not yet bound**.

**MacOS - What happens when running a Debug session?**

Chrome opens and control is shifted back to Visual Studio Code with the breakpoint information showing (e.g. variables data, call stack, etc).

**Win10 - Firefox works**

Interesting side point but Firefox debugging works. When running a Firefox debug session I do have to refresh the initial page load before the breakpoints trigger though.

The breakpoint initially showed the error **Unverified Breakpoint**.  Clicking on this prompted a wizard to add a `pathMappings` to my config.

The Firefox `launch.json` configuration in use on Windows 10 is:

```
    {
      "name": "Launch Firefox",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "pathMappings": [
          {
             "url": "http://localhost:3000/home/rando/dev/sandbox/src",
             "path": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
          }
      ]
    }
```

Note that `/home/rando/dev/sandbox/src` is the location of the app within WSL2 Ubuntu.  MacOS Firefox setup is the same but without the `pathMappings`.

**Conclusion**

At this stage I can only conclude it is something to do with the path mappings needing to be set differently despite [Visual Studio Code WSL documentation hinting no additional changes are required](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_debugging-in-wsl).

Help me, StackOverflow. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran into this and I think I have it working for myself. Using the `.script` command of the `Debugger for Chrome extension`, I saw the below output.

```
› http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js (/__vscode-remote-uri__/home/user/projects/TachiWeb-React/src/static/js/0.chunk.js)
    - /home/user/projects/TachiWeb-React/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/date/now.js (/home/user/projects/TachiWeb-React/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/date/now.js)
```

It seems it doesn't append your webroot to the inferred local path. But using `${webRoot}/*` also doesn't work for some reason. Doing so leads to your path repeating twice like the below result.

```
/__vscode-remote-uri__/home/user/projects/TachiWeb-React/src/home/user/projects/TachiWeb-React/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/date/now.js
```

But manually writing out `"/__vscode-remote-uri__/*"` seems to get round the above duplicate path problem.

This is my working configuration of `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "WSL Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "/*": "/__vscode-remote-uri__/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem I am looking at for most people is a difference on the sourcemap path between the one reflected on Chrome or other browser and the one recognized by vscode. The configuration that worked for me on **Chrome** running (npm start on **wsl**) was as follows:

**My particular solution:**

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "\\mnt\\c\\*": "C:/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Question is: How to debug how source paths are translated into Chrome?**

Here is a simple way:

1. Start the development server with: npm start
2. Launch Chrome in debug mode(F5) with standard configuration (no need to include sourceMapPathOverrides)
3. Go to Chrome Developer console => Sources,
4. Find your file (example App.js) and set a breakpoint there.

[image]

5. Refresh the page and go to vscode.

[image]

6. Set a breakpoint in the same place of the document, in the new file that appeared (/mnt/e/ in my case) and in your file.

[image]

You'll get the idea that you will have to replace "\mnt\e"... with "E:/" in the sourceMapPathOverrides.

Comment: Solved it for me, even when using WSL, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to WSL2 my debugger (only using attach) stopped working.

*I'm using the "Remote WSL" feature on VS Code connecting to my `$wsl/Ubuntu/project-path-here` + Edge (the good one) + Latest VS Code + Win 10 machine with all updates (stable)*

Checking `.scripts` on vscode debug console reveals that my paths are still weird, not repeating, but still weird.

**1 - using the "classic" config (that used to work just fine):**

```
"name": "Attach to Edge",
"type": "edge",
"request": "attach",
"port": 9222,
"url": "http://localhost:4300/*",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

results in this:

```
webpack:///./src/app/component-one/component-one.component.html (\home\my-username\employer-folder\mono-repo\actual-project\src\app\component-one\component-one.component.html)
```

**2 - using the first answer on this post (also from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2068 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/899):**

```
"name": "Attach to Edge",
"type": "edge",
"request": "attach",
"port": 9222,
"url": "http://localhost:4300/*",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
   "/*": "/__vscode-remote-uri__/*"
}
```

results in this (which looks incorrect with the c: usage):

```
webpack:///./src/app/component-one/component-one.component.html (c:\home\my-username\employer-folder\mono-repo\actual-project\webpack:\src\app\component-one\component-one.component.html)
```

At this point I've tried every single combination in the launch.json, even tried to mix **$wsl/Ubuntu** to get the full correct path (checked on `.scripts`) and the breakpoint is always disabled.

Also, when I press the attach it is weirdly fast... it used to take a while (probably checking/using source maps).

Ended up doing the following (wanted to see if the same would happen):

- Added `--start-debugger-server` to my Firefox Developer launch config
- Updated `launch.json` with a new attach config  for FF (also installed Debugger for Firefox extension):
- 

```
"name": "Attach to Firefox",
"type": "firefox",
"request": "attach",
"url": "http://localhost:4300/*",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
```

BINGO, first try... no extra path configs or anything, the way it should be and the way it was before my WSL upgrade (plus no need for port attribute).

P.S: I'll check on my other pc that has a clean Windows 10 2004 + WSL2 install, I'm thinking this might be an "existing/running wsl1 + upgrade to wsl2" thing.

Comment: where exactly did you add  ```-start-debugger-server```? Firefox Developer browser's config file or in vscode or? I could not find any reference on that part

Comment: @eemilk check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop, using Windows here so it's right click in the icon, Properties, add --start-debugger-server at the end of the "Target" value.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the webRoot on **launch.json** worked.
Something like

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/js"
```

or other folder that your webRoot path might be.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away for me the moment I abandoned trying to use Microsoft Edge. Went ahead and installed Chrome, created a launch configuration and it worked.

Comment: The question is about Chrome, not Edge.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to update the `webRoot` attribute in `launch.json`.
My react app was located in /services/web/ so my `launch.json` looks like this:

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/services/web/"
    }
  ]
}
```